# VBA Copy/paste row to other worksheet if cell is greater than cell in other column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

New to VBA, and getting muddled trying to figure out multiple commands at once.

I want to compare the values in column K to the values in column I, and if the value in column K is greater, copy that row and paste it to Sheet9 so that I have a list of all the instances where K > I.

This is what I have:

```
    Sub compareresult()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 8 To 500
    If Cells(i, 11).Value > Cells(i, 9).Value Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.copy
        Sheets("Sheet9").range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Right now it is giving me a 400 error message, but at one point during my messing around it would copy and paste the values on top of each other in Sheet9 so that it only ended up displaying the final time K > I. Any thoughts?

Comment: why do you keep switching the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine this:

```
Sub compareresult()

Dim i As Long, K As Long

K = 1
For i = 8 To 500
    If Cells(i, 11).Value > Cells(i, 9).Value Then
        Cells(i, 11).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet9").Range("A" & K)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

NOTES:

1. we avoid Select
2. we do copy/paste in a single statement
3. we move the destination row down one row at a time

Comment: I'm getting the error message "Subscript out of range"

Comment: @rontob452  Possibly the sheetname is misspelled.  For example,*"Sheet9"* vs *"Sheet 9"*

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Superuser.

This is fairly straightforward, try using the code below. Make sure though to replace "sheet1" with whatever number sheet your source is.

```
 Sub compareresult()

 Dim row1 As Integer
 Dim row2 As Integer

 row2 = 1
 For row1 = 8 To 500
     If sheet1.Cells(row1, 11).value > sheet1.Cells(row1, 9).value Then
         sheet1.Cells(row1, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(11).Cells(row2, 1)
         row2 = row2 + 1
     End If
 Next row1

 End Sub
```

Things to notice:

1. We do not use any selections or activations, which is faster.
2. We copy and paste in one statement, which is faster.
3. We move the destination row down one at a time, which makes our code faster.
4. We move refer to both the source and destination sheets by number, which is safer.
5. We use meaningful variable names, which helps the readability of our code.